# Como fazer um software sobrepor a desktop e games fullscreen?

Tags: python

Olá, gostaria de saber o nome dessa técnica onde deixamos o software mostrar algo sobrepondo desktop e programas fullscreen e etc...

Exemplo:
Criei um programa que exibe o horário atual, e eu quero que o horario seja mostrado enquanto eu jogo ou acesso a internet, mesmo com o software em segundo plano.

Como faço isso em python? É possivel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ser complicado dependendo do modo de exibição do jogo, se o jogo estiver em modo full screen exclusivo quer dizer que ele tem prioridade sobre a tela e nenhum outro aplicativo poderá exibir nada alem dele, já em outros modos como janela ou janela tela inteira pode-se fazer uma sobreposição de modo bem fácil.

Aplicativos como o Discord por exemplo fazem essa sobreposição "`Overlay` nome da técnica" diretamente no `DirectX`, porem se você for fazer isso em jogos onlines com proteção anti-hack muito provavelmente você vai ser detectado já que esta a modificar o gráfico do jogo de modo não autorizado.

Como eu disse se o jogo não estiver em full screen modo exclusivo você pode utilizar uma `API` do Windows para fazer a sobreposição da sua janela dentro do jogo, ou seja a sua janela vai se tornar filha da janela do jogo como um se fosse modal.

Exemplo e C#:

```
    // API Windows
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    // Pega o processo - Jogo CS GO
    Process hostProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo")[0];
    // Pega o identificador da minha janela overlay janela Handle
    IntPtr hostHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    // Pega o identificador da janela do CS GO
    IntPtr guestHandle = hostProcess.MainWindowHandle;

    // Seta a janela filho......
    SetParent(hostHandle, guestHandle);
```

Não utilizo Python mas a `API` pode ser utilizada com ele normalmente, os parâmetros para ela são as `Handles` das janelas, para saber mais -> https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setparent.